# Hibernate : Many-to-Many Mapped entity (with hierarchy) fails to save returning ObjectRetrievalFailureException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring-Boot application I have an entity that contains a many-to-many mapped set as follows:

```
  @Entity
  public class ShowRoom implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "room_id")
   private String roomId;

   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "relate_block_input",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "room_id", referencedColumnName = "room_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id", referencedColumnName = "vehicle_id")
    )
   private Set<Vehicle> vehicles;

   //getters setters and other fields
  }
```

vehicle entity is:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Vehicle{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "vehicle_id")
    private String vehicleId;

    //getters setters and other fields
}
```

as it may be seen in the previous entity it has some child entities :

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "car")
public class Car extends Vehicle{
    private Integer horsePower;

    //getters setters and other fields
}
```

and this:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "bus")
public class Bus extends Vehicle{
    private Integer passengerCount;

    //getters setters and other fields
}
```

what I'm trying to do here is to reach the content of the child entities to save them using the default `save` method that exists in the `ShowRoomRepository`.
I succeeded in fetching the content of the `vehicle` entity with all the child content without any errors. But when I try to save the content (e.g. insert new entry) I have the following error thrown:

```
org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException: Object [id=null] was not of the specified subclass [com.example.entities.Vehicle] : class of the given object did not match class of persistent copy; nested exception is org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=null] was not of the specified subclass [com.example.entities.Vehicle] : class of the given object did not match class of persistent copy
```

My question now is how can I fix this problem , or maybe let me say can I persist the data using this method? or should I map all the child entities one by one in the `showroom` entity, or is there a workaround for this?
Any help is welcomed , thanks.

## Edit:

---

as for data access I'm using the following repository.

```
@Repository
public interface CardInputRepository extends JpaRepository<ShowRoom ,String>{
findByRoomId(String roomId);
}
```

As it is seen I didn't specify special `save` method, I'm just using the default method that exists in the `JpaRepository`.

Comment: Might it be that you are actually trying to save an instance of `Vehicle`? In any case you should make `Vehicle` `abstract`.

Comment: the instance I'm trying to save is a `ShowRoom` instance. I will try to make it abstract but I'm not very possitive about this , since -as I mentioned- `find` queries are working flawlessly.

Comment: and no making it abstract didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Without seeing the actual data access code, it's impossible to tell bu just looking at the mappings.

Comment: @VladMihalcea I have added the data access code. btw this error is not thrown any more but it is now unable to set the `DiscriminatorColumn` value  since it can't be insertable nor updatable. for this reason now I can only save the data that exists in the parent (in this case `Vehicle` class), while ignoring the child entity content since seemingly it's unable to distinguish which child this is. Is there a way to solve this too?. Thanks for your attention

Comment: I tried to understand your problem, but I still don't get it. From what I can tell, you have more than one issue. Just try to read the Hibernate User Guide to get familiar with inheritance and associations, and you'll have a better chance to deal with your issues.